# Array elements changing values?

Tags: c++

```
int m;
cin >> m;
int d[m],g[m];
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++){
cin >> g[i] >> d[i];
}
```

I set m to be 3. Then I set g[i] and d[i] to be 2 and 9 , 5 and 25 , 16 and 24 (first number is g[i] and second is d[i]). And later in the program d[1] isn't 9 , it's 24. Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: There is quite a few mistakes in this code.  If you are just starting C++, I suggest you get a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn from there.

Comment: In your loop i should start from 0 to m-1. And m should be set before declaration of d and g

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer a variable length array (VLA) (which AFAIK, is not in the standard and might not be supported by all compilers, but I could be wrong about it) instead of a plain `std::vector` ?

Comment: Long explanation short: undefined behavior due to creating VLAs (which are, technically, non-standard C++, in the first place) having the size of a value contained in an uninitialized variable.

Comment: This code snippet can't be compiled as-is. Please post a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: What do you think happens in line 2 of your code snippet?

Comment: I made a mistake writing this on stackoverflow read the post again

Comment: @AndrejVujic "_I made a mistake writing this on stackoverflow read the post again_" Still undefined behavior. Even if you are using a compiler, that allows VLAs, you are writing past the end of each array. Array indexes start at `0`, as was already mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

```
int m;
int d[m],g[m],
cin >> m;
```

> I set m to be 3. Then I set g[i] and d[i] to be 2 and 9

Notice that you're declaring `g` and `d` before you even set `m`.

```
int m;
int d[m],g[m],
```

This is undefined behaviour: `m` is uninitialised and you're trying to use the value of it.

As commenters have pointed out, you're using Variable Length Arrays, which are an extension of a compiler gcc, but not standard C++. It would be good to break the habit now.

You can fix your code by defining `m` first, such as `const int m = 3;` and then don't bother reading it from `std::cin`.

Notice also that you are going to go out of bounds in your `for` loop:

```
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++){
```

Arrays are indexed from `0`, so it should be `for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)`.

Taking it a step further, you can read it in from `std::cin`, and then define `d` and `g` as `std::vector`:

```
int m = 0;
std::cin >> m;
std::vector<int> d(m), g(m);
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
```

Something you won't want to hear: Given the simple mistakes made here, you should really start learning C++ from a book, and not however you're trying to learn it right now.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `std::cin << m;` -> `std::cin >> m;`

Comment: Haha that's more than a nitpick that was a massive error, thanks for the catch!

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. I saw it as a simple typo, hence - minor nitpick :)

Answer (score 0):

In case this is a HW assignment and you aren't allowed to use `vector`, use a `dynamic array`.

```
cin >> m;
int * a1 = new int[m];
int * a2 = new int[m];
```

Make sure to `delete []` these arrays manually when you are done using them, as there is no automatic garbage collector to clean up after you.